java + how to tune ParallelGCThread for G1GC
tuning the Java Virtual Machine is very challenging
and from our last investigation we saw improvement when increasing the value of ParallelGCThread
but in fact we want to know the formula that gives us the right tuning
for example according to https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028810372-Java-Virtual-Machine-Tuning
we see the following instrunctions
Note: the ParallelGCThreads value (e.g., ParallelGCThreads=16) varies based on the type of CPUs available. Set the value according to CPU specification. On Linux machines, report the number of available CPUs by running cat /proc/cpuinfo.
so seems that tuning should be according to number of machine CORE's
but what in case for example machine has 96 CORE's ? is it make sense to change the flag as ParallelGCThreads=96 ?
or we need to do some  benchmark about this ?
my post is regarding the Hadoop cluster and we want to tune the namenode and datanodes to the right memory settings for G1GC
